# How to update XML elements with new values in SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have XML in one of the column in the `XYZ` table, and I need to update the `Amount` element with a new value instead of 0.00, and the `PolicyReference` and `AccountReference` elements with two different values instead of blank.

For example:

```
<PolicyReference>7657576567</PolicyReference>
<AccountReference>7657576875</AccountReference>
```

This is my XML in the column :

```
<document>
    <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
    <PaymentMethodDetail>
        <EFT>
            <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
            <AccountName>ABCDEFGHIJK</AccountName>
        </EFT>
    </PaymentMethodDetail>
    <PaymentExtendedData>
        <CHECK>
            <Source>System</Source>
            <SourceType>ACH</SourceType>
        </CHECK>
    </PaymentExtendedData>
    <PostMarkDate />
    <EntryUserId>1</EntryUserId>
    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
    <EntryDate />
    <PolicyLineOfBusiness>LOL</PolicyLineOfBusiness>
    <PolicyReference />
    <AccountReference />
    <AccountId>2034001793</AccountId>
</document>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE XYZ
SET XmlPayload.modify('replace value of (//document/PolicyReference/)[1] with "<PolicyReference>275654</PolicyReference>"')
WHERE PaymentSearchId = 18785
```

I am getting an error:

> Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> XQuery [XYZ.XmlPayload.modify()]: Syntax error near ')', expected a step expression

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: UPDATE XYZ SET XmlPayload.modify(' + '''replace value of(//document/PolicyReference/text())[1] with "' <PolicyReference> + 546545  + </PolicyReference> '")
       PaymentReferenceNumber = ''' 546545 '''

Comment: Its not working, please correct me what I am doing mistake here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good question as it presents an interesting challenge of having an existing element without a text value. This is handled differently than simply adding a new element or replacing the contents of an existing one.

First, though, your provided XML was broken. If that is the XML you're receiving, you have other issues. For instance, in your original question, you had `</AccountReference>` which is invalid syntax by itself. I corrected this to `<AccountReference />` both in your question as well as in my example.

With empty XML elements, you need to call the `insert text` DML of the XML.modify method.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<document>
    <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
    <PaymentMethodDetail>
       <EFT>
          <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
          <AccountName>ABCDEFGHIJK</AccountName>
       </EFT>
    </PaymentMethodDetail>
    <PaymentExtendedData>
       <CHECK>
          <Source>System</Source>
          <SourceType>ACH</SourceType>
        </CHECK>
    </PaymentExtendedData>
    <PostMarkDate />
    <EntryUserId>1</EntryUserId>
    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
    <EntryDate />
    <PolicyLineOfBusiness>LOL</PolicyLineOfBusiness>
    <PolicyReference />
    <AccountReference />
    <AccountId>2034001793</AccountId>
</document>';

DECLARE 
    @Amount DECIMAL(18,2) = 99.95,
    @AccountReference VARCHAR(20) = '7657576875',
    @PolicyReference VARCHAR(20) = '7657576567';

/* Update Amount */
SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/document/Amount/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@Amount")
');

/* Insert the AccountReference text */
SET @xml.modify('
    insert text {sql:variable("@AccountReference")} into (/document/AccountReference[1])[1]
');

/* Insert the PolicyReference text */
SET @xml.modify('
    insert text {sql:variable("@PolicyReference")} into (/document/PolicyReference[1])[1]
');

/* Show updated XML */
SELECT @xml;
```

The updated XML is now:

```
<document>
  <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
  <PaymentMethodDetail>
    <EFT>
      <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
      <AccountName>ABCDEFGHIJK</AccountName>
    </EFT>
  </PaymentMethodDetail>
  <PaymentExtendedData>
    <CHECK>
      <Source>System</Source>
      <SourceType>ACH</SourceType>
    </CHECK>
  </PaymentExtendedData>
  <PostMarkDate />
  <EntryUserId>1</EntryUserId>
  <Amount>99.95</Amount>
  <EntryDate />
  <PolicyLineOfBusiness>LOL</PolicyLineOfBusiness>
  <PolicyReference>7657576567</PolicyReference>
  <AccountReference>7657576875</AccountReference>
  <AccountId>2034001793</AccountId>
</document>
```

**An example of updating a table:**

```
DECLARE @xyz TABLE ( PaymentSearchId INT, XmlPayload XML );
INSERT INTO @xyz VALUES ( 18785, 
'<document>
    <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
    <PaymentMethodDetail>
       <EFT>
          <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
          <AccountName>ABCDEFGHIJK</AccountName>
       </EFT>
    </PaymentMethodDetail>
    <PaymentExtendedData>
       <CHECK>
          <Source>System</Source>
          <SourceType>ACH</SourceType>
        </CHECK>
    </PaymentExtendedData>
    <PostMarkDate />
    <EntryUserId>1</EntryUserId>
    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
    <EntryDate />
    <PolicyLineOfBusiness>LOL</PolicyLineOfBusiness>
    <PolicyReference />
    <AccountReference />
    <AccountId>2034001793</AccountId>
</document>' );

DECLARE 
    @PaymentSearchId INT = 18785,
    @Amount DECIMAL(18,2) = 99.95,
    @AccountReference VARCHAR(20) = '7657576875',
    @PolicyReference VARCHAR(20) = '7657576567';

/* Update Amount */
UPDATE @xyz
SET XmlPayload.modify('
    replace value of (/document/Amount/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@Amount")
')
WHERE PaymentSearchId = @PaymentSearchId;

/* Insert the AccountReference text */
UPDATE @xyz
SET XmlPayload.modify('
    insert text {sql:variable("@AccountReference")} into (/document/AccountReference[1])[1]
')
WHERE PaymentSearchId = @PaymentSearchId;

/* Insert the PolicyReference text */
UPDATE @xyz
SET XmlPayload.modify('
    insert text {sql:variable("@PolicyReference")} into (/document/PolicyReference[1])[1]
')
WHERE PaymentSearchId = @PaymentSearchId;

/* Show updated XML */
SELECT XmlPayload FROM @xyz WHERE PaymentSearchId = @PaymentSearchId;
```