# Update XML element value with new values in SQL Script

Tags: sql, .net

I have XML in one of the column in the XYZ Table, here i Need to update Amount tag with new value instead of 0.00 and then PolicyReference and AccountReference I need to update two different values in these tags instead of Blank .
For example -

```
 <PolicyReference>7657576567</PolicyReference>
                  <AccountReference>7657576875</AccountReference>
```

This is my XML inside the column :-

```
<document>
  <StatusCode>ACV</StatusCode>
  <PaymentMethodDetail>
    <EFT>
      <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
      <AccountName>ABCDEFGHIJK</AccountName>
    </EFT>
  </PaymentMethodDetail>
  <PaymentExtendedData>
    <CHECK>
      <Source>System</Source>
      <SourceType>ACH</SourceType>
    </CHECK>
  </PaymentExtendedData>
  <PostMarkDate />
  <EntryUserId>1</EntryUserId>
  <Amount>0.00</Amount>
  <EntryDate />
  <PolicyLineOfBusiness>LOL</PolicyLineOfBusiness>
  </PolicyReference>
  </AccountReference>
  <AccountId>2034001793</AccountId>
</document>
```

This is what I have tried :-

```
Update XYZ
SET XmlPayload.modify('replace value of (//document/PolicyReference/)[1] with "<PolicyReference>275654</PolicyReference>"')
where PaymentSearchId =18785
```

I am getting an error message, please suggest me :-
Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
XQuery [XYZ.XmlPayload.modify()]: Syntax error near ')', expected a step expression.

Comment: You should edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171363/), not create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it  - use the string Replace to do it with string because your XML is not a valid XML and XML functionality will not work for it. But string will

```
UPDATE XYZ
SET XmlPayload = REPLACE(CAST(XmlPayload AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ' </PolicyReference>', '<PolicyReference>7657576567</PolicyReference>')
WHERE PaymentSearchId =18785
```

Comment: No, it will not work, as i showed in the XML , current XML tag is like this - </PolicyReference>, so now i need to update like this - <PolicyReference> 275654</PolicyReference>

Comment: I mean I need to add complete XML tag like starting and ending of that tag

Comment: @user613400 Oh... well. I see. Then you out of luck with XML because that "xml" is not xml or invalid xml. BUT you are not out of luck completele - SEE MY updated answer